# Picard numbers of isogenous K3 surfaces over a non-closed field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, divisors, k3-surfaces

Let $S_1, S_2$ be K3 surfaces defined over a field $k$ and $\phi\!: S_1 \dashrightarrow S_2$ a dominant rational $k$-map (so-called isogeny). It is known that $\rho(S_1) = \rho(S_2)$ for the complex field $k = \mathbb{C}$, i.e., the Picard numbers (ranks of the Picard $k$-groups) are equal.

Is this true if $k$ is a non-closed field, for example $k = \mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, and $S_1, S_2$ are non-supersingular?